# Freelancer in India working for Swiss Company

Tags: taxes, india, salary

I am based in India and I have a contract with a Swiss company to handle their businesses in and around India. I receive my Salary in Eur which is then converted to INR in my Bank.
I have been paying taxes oevr the last two years but I wanted to be sure if at all I am required to pay the taxes as even the company is paying the taxes/ deductions for the salary paid.
Can someone please guide me on this part?

Thanks,
Joe A

Answer (score 1):

I am a freelancer based in Europe and I want to tell you:
- if you are a freelancer, then you INVOICE your Swizzerland based client
The word salary is improper.
- So your client will DEDUCE the invoice from its taxes, and NOT pay income tax on top of that invoice. Because invoice = expense.

So, ONLY YOU pay income tax in India.
Your client pays no tax at all, not in India, not in Swizzerland.
As you are a freelancer and not employee, the company has no obligation to pay employer taxes for you. A company  has financial benefits from working with a freelancer.

Answer (score 0):

As you are earning an income by working in India, you are required to pay tax in India. If you contract is of freelance, then the income earned by you has to be self declared and taxes paid accordingly. There are some expenses one can claim, a CA should be able to guide you.

Not sure why the Swiss comapny is paying taxes?. Are they depositing this with Income Tax, India, do they have a TAN Number. If yes, then you don't need to pay tax. But you need to get a statement from your company showing the tax paid on behalf of you. You can also verify the tax paid on your behalf via "http://incometaxindia.gov.in/26ASTaxCreditStatement.asp" you cna register.
Alternatively if you have a Bank Account in India with a PAN card on their records, most Banks provide a link to directly see

Answer (score 0):

I have some more inputs to investigate:

India has dual tax avoidance treaty signed with european countries so that NRIs dont pay tax in both countries. Please check if India has some agreement with Swiss

Also for freelance job that is delivered from India, u need to make sure where you have to pay taxes as you are still in India so the term NRI will not hold good here.

Also, if Swiss company is paying tax there, and you are  a freelancer from India(resident in india) how to tax filing /rate etc has to be investigated.

Also, can you apply for tax back from swiss( a portion of tax paid can be refunded eg: in Germany) but I dont know if this is true for Freelancers and also for people out side SWISS.

Bip